# Run ASP.NET application in a sub-folder of localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, localhost

Is it possible to run ASP.NET application in a subfolder of localhost ? E.g. "localhost:61778/subfolder/" instead of "localhost:61778/"?

I will publish my web application into sub-folder on real host like "www.mysite.com/subfolder/". I want to test that all patches will be builds correctly and sub-folder will be used (I need to save and restore some files).

Another question is **How to get website directory with a sub-folder** like "www.mysite.com/subfolder/" where a website is deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install IIS on your local machine and create an application  over IIS (localhost/ApplicationName).

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks! ;)